# Repeated Images when using UIL on gridview android

Tags: android, gridview, universal-image-loader

I'm using gridview to load images locally and using Universal image loader, but I have one problem and there is no solution benefited me, that even though there is no repeated drawable on my images and they are unique at all, the image loader duplicate some images.

```
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.SimpleBitmapDisplayer;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;

public class customizedGrid extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final Integer[] Imageid;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public customizedGrid(Context c, Integer[] mImageIds) {
        mContext = c;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.images).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
                .delayBeforeLoading(1000)
                .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer()).build();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
        this.Imageid = mImageIds;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Imageid.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Imageid[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(125, 125));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageLoader.displayImage("drawable://" + Imageid[position], imageView,
                options);
        // imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

And I tried to use Image Holder but the performance issue is exist

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unit, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        grid.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) grid.getTag();
    holder.image.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
    return grid;
    /*
     * imageLoader.displayImage("drawable://" //
     * +Imageid[Integer.parseInt(imageView
     * .getTag().toString())],imageView,options);
     * imageView.setImageResource(
     * Imageid[Integer.parseInt(imageView.getTag() .toString())]);
     */

}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image;
}
```

Comment: Use `ViewHolder` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is like the imageview first shows an existing image and then displays real image after some time try to set a default image before the line

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

add

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);  // a default image
```

if this's not the issue

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int currentposition=position;
ImageView imageView;

if (convertView == null) {

    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(125, 125));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
} else {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
}
imageview.setTag(currentposition);
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageLoader.displayImage("drawable://" +   Imageid[Integer.parseInt(imageview.getTag().toString())], imageView,
        options);
// imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
return imageView;
```

}

Comment: No, I set this on the configuration of image loader, and the default image  is works normally.

The problem is that there are some duplicate images shown on the gridview. and I'm sure my images are unique and there are no duplicate among them.

Comment: So sorry, that didn't solve the problem, the problem is same.

Comment: @user3305603 please post the code updated with mycode.Usually setting position works for gridview and listview with UIL